# How to use multiple templates that inherits from one base template? python, Flask

Tags: python, html, templates, flask, web-deployment

I have my directory structure as such (from https://github.com/alvations/APE):

```
APE
    \app
        \templates
            base.html
            index.html
            instance.html
        __init__.py
        hamlet.py
    config.py
    run.py
```

My `hamlet.py` application, initializes 2 pages with these functions:

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@app.route('/instance')

def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def instance():
    return render_template('instance.html')
```

And the `instance.html` and `index.html` are both inheriting from `base.html` with different block content, the base.html looks as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Post Editor Z</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div><!-- /.container -->

    </body>
</html>
```

My index.html looks like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}    
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      Hello World
    </div>
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And my instance.html looks like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}    
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      Some instance.
    </div>
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

After deploying and going to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/index` and `http://127.0.0.1:5000/instance`. They were both giving the content of `index.html`

**Is that because base.html can only be inherited by one other html? In my case, I have both `instance` and `index` html inheriting from base.html.**

I have tried making a copy of `base.html` and call it `abase.html` and made `instance.html` inherits from `abase.html` but `instance.html` still outputs `Hello World` instead of `Some instance.`, i.e. i did this change to `instance.html`:

```
{% extends "abase.html" %}
{% block content %}    
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      Hello World
    </div>
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**How do I resolve the problem such that instance.html and index.html will display the two different pages as defined in the templates?**

Is it because I am initializing my pages wrongly in `hamlet.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix for the problem but I don't know why it works.

Shifting the `@app.route('/instance')` to before the `instance()` worked:

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app

@app.route('/')

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/instance')
def instance():
    return render_template('instance.html')
```

Comment: It works because `@app.route` is a decorator of a function. Written like before, every url was pointing to index function. This way you have `/instance` for `instance()` and others for `index()`.

Comment: If `@app.route('/')` is decorating nothing and the next function is `@app.route('index')`. The default page will point to the `index()`?

Comment: `@app.route('/')` is decorating `index` in this example together with `@app.route('/index')`. Right now your default page is `index()`.